# Не отрабатывает контекстный процессор

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь добавить контекстный процессор custom_proc, чтобы передать переменные в контекст шаблона. Код:

```
def custom_proc(request):
    """A context processor that provides 'app', 'user' and 'ip_address'."""
    return {
        'app': 'MyApp',
        'user': request.user,
        'ip_address': request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
    }


def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('core/index-main.html')
    context = RequestContext(
        request,
        {
            'message': 'My message'
        },
        processors=[custom_proc]
    )
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

При этом переменные из custom_proc в шаблон не попадают.

Если вместо подгрузки шаблона, я укажу его прямо в строке:

```
template = Template('{{ app }} {{ user }} {{ ip_address }}')
```

то контекстный процессор отрабатывает и переменные попадают в шаблон.

Поиск по коду показал, что для биндинга переменных необходимо передать query вторым параметром в render, но при попытке сделать:

```
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

приложение вылетает с ошибкой:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\var\www\RQ30\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
  response = get_response(request)
File "E:\var\www\RQ30\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
  response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "E:\var\www\RQ30\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "E:\var\www\RQ30\aisog\aisog\core\views.py", line 27, in index
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request=request))
File "E:\var\www\RQ30\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 64, in render
  context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)
File "E:\var\www\RQ30\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 267, in make_context
  context.push(original_context)
File "E:\var\www\RQ30\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 59, in push
  return ContextDict(self, *dicts, **kwargs)
File "E:\var\www\RQ30\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 18, in __init__
  super(ContextDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

Вопрос: что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте создать новый файл `context_processors.py`
такого содержания:

```
def custom_proc(request):
    """A context processor that provides 'app', 'user' and 'ip_address'."""
    return {
        'app': 'MyApp',
        'user': request.user,
        'ip_address': request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
    }
```

В `TEMPLATES` в файле `settings.py` добавьте Ваш файл `context_processors.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...,
                'YOU_PROJECT.context_processors.custom_proc',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

И перепишите `index`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
  return HttpResponse(render(request, 'index.html', context={'message': 'My ip'}))
```

Comment: Но это же будет глобальный процессор? Который будет добавлять данные во все формы?

Comment: Тогда в `index` добавить переменную `context` в виде словаря, без использования функции `custom_proc`

Answer (score 1):

А почему не пользуетесь Class Based Views?

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class CustomProcTemplateView(TemplateView):

   def get_context(self):
       request = self.request
       context = super(CustomProcTemplateView, self).get_context()
       context.update({
        'app': 'MyApp',
        'user': request.user,
        'ip_address': request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
       })
       return context

class IndexView(CustomProcTemplateView):
    template_name = 'core/index-main.html'

# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'', CustomProcTemplateView.as_view()),
   ...
]
```

Классы же на порядок удобнее, можно наследовать, писать миксины, проверку прав. А с FBV приходится каждый раз это вписывать во вьюху.